# TFS feature equivalent in git - get latest update to uncommited code base

Tags: git, tfs

We have switched our source control from TFS to git.
In TFS there was a very useful feature that we don't have in git.

I want to do a pull request while working on another part of the code base without doing a commit first, but willing to do a merge in case of conflicts.

Scenario: I am working on a new feature while my peer found and fixed a critical bug that would effect my development. My feature isn't ready yes so I don't want to commit the changes, but I do wan't to pull my peer's changes. This is not possible in git.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

In that situation I would just commit locally and not push it.  Then pull in the other changes to my local branch.  You can always squash the commit later before you push it to the server if you wish.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Git is a different source control paradigm than TFVC and it's a bad idea to try to use the same workflows between the two.

Answer (score 1):

We are talking about [git-stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Assume:

- You are working in branch `feature/my-new-feature`
- Your peer fixed some bug in `bugfix/their-critical-bugfixes`
- You have uncommited changes in feature/my-new-feature but you need to get fix from `bugfix/their-critical-bugfixes`

You can solve this problem with this steps:

- `git stash` # you in your branch feature/my-new-feature
- `git fetch origin` # get last changes
- `git pull ./ origin/bugfix/their-critical-bugfixes` # merge your branch with their bugfixes
- resolve conflicts if exists
- `git stash apply` # apply your stashed changes # so your uncommited changes also with you:)